# "May I borrow your notebooks? They 'will' help me understand the subject more." Why we use "will" there?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, conditionals

I don't know why we use **will** because we don't know whether others will do what we ask or not. I wonder whether there is actually an omitted if-clause there.

**Example 1:**

> May I borrow your notebooks? *They **will** help me understand the subject more* (if you lend me the notebooks).

**Example 2:**

> You have to give me advice. *Your advice **will** give me more background knowledge about what to major* (if you give me advice).

Comment: *Will* also expresses hope in what the speaker is saying. Whether that hope is well-founded or not depends on the situation.

Comment: The *meaning* of the "if"-clauses is naturally understood from the context. I wouldn't even say it's an omitted "if"-clause though. Nobody is filling in that blank in their heads. It's just the natural thing to understand.

Comment: @gotube Thank you. I found many similar cases in everyday life. For example, "You got lost? You can go to the police station, and the officers there 'will' tell you the direction." or "I will teach you how to set up your phone. You can click the home button, and a new window 'will' show up." Are they also cases where the meaning of the "if"-clauses is naturally understood?

Comment: The function of "and" in those sentences is "...and when you do...", which is similar to "if".

Answer (score -2):

The phrase:

> They will help me...

Is unlikely to be accurate.  This should be more correctly stated as:

> I believe they will help me understand the subject more...

In the second case, something like:

> I feel as though your advice will give me more...

People do, however, often use such language in casual conversation so you will likely hear and even read something similar.

Comment: I think it's quite likely that another person's notes will help you, especially if you have none.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question about whether an elided "if" clause in implied.